# How to allow other machines in same LAN (PC/Mac/Mobile Devices) to download from our Electron app?

Tags: electron, lan

The question is weird but it’s because I don’t even have any knowledge about this concept.

Here is the thing:
I’m working with an Electron app that is a whiteboard application.

A user can draw something onto the board and export it to PDF.

This PDF will be saved into a folder (I assume AppData folder on Windows or something like that on MacOS), so that other machines can access (download) it.

Now I don’t know how to allow other machines to download this file.

Normally we will need to share the folder (on Windows), and other machines can go to Networks/our-machine to find and download the shared files.

But the owner of this app said that we can download it if both machines are on the same LAN, using some kind of URL like 192.168.x.x:6554/mypdfile_somerandomid.pdf

(this URL can then be turned into a QR code so that mobile devices can use camera to access the link quickly)

I don’t know how is this possible. Can you please suggest some solutions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[Writing URLs](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/nautilus-connect.html.en)

> A URL, or uniform resource locator, is a form of address that refers
> to a location or file on a network. The address is formatted like
> this:
>
> scheme://servername.example.com/folder
>
> The scheme specifies the protocol or type of server. The example.com
> portion of the address is called the domain name. If a username is
> required, it is inserted before the server name:
>
> scheme://username@servername.example.com/folder
>
> Some schemes require the port number to be specified. Insert it after
> the domain name:
>
> scheme://servername.example.com:port/folder

Without public share that windows offers, you will need other third party software to accomplish what you want, which will do the same as windows does.
Better just share the folder your Electron app uses to export PDFs.

Comment: Thanks, but my client needs to allow mobile (android/ios) to download this file also (because it's just .pdf file so a phone can read it too.

Comment: @HoangTrinh Please clarify how client wishes to access those URLs, using what app? In your post you did not mentioned mobile devices, only "machines on same LAN".